# Terrafrom local-exec ansible error /bin/sh: 1: ansible-playbook: not found

Tags: ansible, terraform

I'm trying to test Terraform calling Ansible playbooks via local-exec

I'm running into the following error

```
null_resource.pb_add_main: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.pb_add_main (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "    ansible-playbook hw.yml\n"]
null_resource.pb_add_main (local-exec): /bin/sh: 1: ansible-playbook: not found
╷
│ Error: Error running command '    ansible-playbook hw.yml
│ ': exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: 1: ansible-playbook: not found
```

Not sure how to correct this ......... any help is greatly appreciated!

Ive seen reference to ansible been installed - which it is, `executable location = /usr/bin/ansible`

and do an `echo $PATH` in your local-exec command and confirm if ansible is present in the given path

```
null_resource.echo (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo $PATH"]
null_resource.pb_add_main: Creating...
null_resource.echo (local-exec): /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

## Additional Info

**New CentOS build**

```
sudo dnf install -y dnf-plugins-core
sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/RHEL/hashicorp.repo
sudo yum install terraform
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install ansible
```

**Ansible version is**

```
[user@centos-automate config_deploy_del]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.23
  config file = /home/user/config_deploy_del/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Jul 15 2021, 15:17:46) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-2)]
```

**Terraform is being executed from**

```
[user@centos-automate config_deploy_del]$ pwd
/home/user/config_deploy_del
```

**tf and pb files are all in the same directory**

```
[user@centos-automate config_deploy_del]$ ls -la
total 72
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user    0 Aug  5 18:13 ansible.cfg
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user  145 Aug  5 18:13 backend.tf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user  228 Aug  5 18:13 hw.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user  855 Aug  5 18:13 pb.tf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user  140 Aug  5 18:13 providers.tf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user  321 Aug  5 18:13 variables.tf
```

**tf file** `pb.tf`

```
resource "null_resource" "echo" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo $PATH"
  }
}
resource "null_resource" "pb_add_main" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    ansible-playbook hw.yml
    EOT
  }
}
```

**tf file alterations** `pb.tf` results in same error

```
........
resource "null_resource" "pb_add_main" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook hw.yml"
  }
}
```

**Path combinations** to ansible and playbook - none work

`/usr/bin/ansible-playbook hw.yml` and

`/usr/bin/ansible-playbook /home/user/config_deploy_del/hw.yml` and

`ansible-playbook /home/user/config_deploy_del/hw.yml`

**Started to look at this line**

Interesting - I've started to look at this line here

`(local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "ansible-playbook hw.yml"]`

if you run this from the CMDL......... just by itself - the play executes

`[user@centos-automate config_deploy_del]$ /bin/sh -c "ansible-playbook hw.yml"`

## Potential Fix - working then NOT

I got a tip that `ansible` needed to be installed via `pip`, not via `yum` or `apt-get`

On a spare ubunbtu VM I did the following - which allowed `local-exec` to execute the playbook

**HOWEVER** this only worked a few times and when I updated my working `.tf` and `.yml` files to run my workflow it failed again.

I reverted my files and it continued to fail.......

```
curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install terraform
terraform -help
touch ~/.bashrc
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install ansible
```

I followed this process on CentOS and it **DID NOT** work

```
sudo dnf install -y dnf-plugins-core
sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/RHEL/hashicorp.repo
sudo yum update
sudo yum install terraform
sudo yum install python3
sudo yum install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo pip3 install ansible
```

Comment: What happens if you provide full path to `ansible-playbook`?

Comment: Edit main question above with your suggestion - none of the combos worked

Comment: How do you invoke it when you ssh to the instance manually? What is the path used?

Comment: Because Terraform and Ansible are on the same Ubuntu server that I'm ssh'd to (hence `local-exec`), I just issued  `/bin/sh -c "ansible-playbook hw.yml"` from this path `/home/user/config_deploy_del`

Comment: By any chance did you ever solve this? I ran into the same problem, but for me it was because I was using Terraform Cloud as my backend with the workspace set to Remote Execution Mode. Basically, Remote Execution Mode means you are running your config on their servers, which do not have Ansible installed (hence the "ansible-playbook: not found" error message). If I change the Terraform Cloud workspace Execution Mode to Local, it works because then it is running on my machine instead of theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late but probably you need to add the `working_dir` argument to the `provision local-exec` statement.

See: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec